# csc stopped working in visual studio 2017 IIS Express

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0, csc

in visual studio i'm working with asp.net core i have created a new MVC Project but when i tried to run it on IIS Express it gives error CSC.exe has stopped working

[image]

it shows this error when i click close this program then this error

[image]

i have tried Delete bin folder

reinstall vs2017

created new project still facing these errors

what is the solution?

Comment: I am having same issue... did you resolve this?

Comment: i have tried but no even i install visual studio again still problem not solved then i installed operating system it solved obviously